# No "iOS Development" signing certificate matching team with a private key was found

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, provisioning-profile

I acquired the project from the previous team of developers that were outsourced. They have provided me with all the credentials and files for the IOS app but I do not have the password for the certificate, so when I try to archive and submit new version for testing it shows that No "iOS Development" signing certificate matching team ID with a private key was found. Do I need to just create a new certificate and profile for that? I can no longer contact the previous developer.

I have already tried downloading the provisioning profiles and added the certificates(.cer) on my keychain but I think it need the other certificate with the password.